# sshd Authorized key command not authenticating user

Tags: authentication, ssh, ldap, rhel7

I'm using Simple AD to authenticate SSH users on a RHEL 7.2 server. I've modified the schema on the AD to include the LDAP parameter for sshPublicKey and ldapPublicKey and imported the public key to the AD for my user.

I can authenticate against the AD fine using a password login. I can return the SSH key from the AD using the following command

```
/usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys user@domain.example.com
```

I can even manually copy that returned key into /home/user@domain.example.com/.ssh/authorized_keys and can log in absolutely fine.

However when I add the following to sshd_config and restart sshd I can't authenticate (just get permssion denied)

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

To summarise, I can authenticate against the AD fine using a passowrd, I can return the public key from the AD fine (and authenticate against the key when I manaually copy it to authorized_keys) but I can't get it to work using sshd's AuthorizedKeysCommand

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was just some extra spaces in after the AuthorizedKeysCommand file. Noticed it by starting sshd with debug:

```
systemctl stop sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

I then saw when attempting an ssh connection:

```
Could not stat AuthorizedKeysCommand "/usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys  ": No such file or directory
```